Driver's license in Canada with exchange application abroad
I submitted a driver's license exchange application in Norway, so my Canadian driver's license is being held at the local office. However, I won't be able to get a Norwegian driver's license on time due to the unavailability of time slots to take a practical test. Now I have plans to travel to Canada soon, but if I take my Canadian driver's license back from the Norwegian office, I will have to submit the driver's license exchange application again later on, but because the rules in Norway changed while my application was still in process, resubmitting the application will require taking several additional traffic courses.
So, what are my options? Can I still request a replacement of my driver's license in Canada when I come there for a visit?

Can I still request a replacement of my driver's license in Canada when I come there for a visit? - sure, you can lie and say you lost it... Not sure how legal that would be.

@littleadv You mean, if I say that it's in the process of being exchanged and explain everything, they won't give me a replacement license?

I don't think so, the whole point of surrendering the license is that you can no longer use it.

@littleadv It could be trickier than that, but could be not. Since I'm authorized to drive in Canada, why should I be deprived of this right. Doesn't seem to make sense to me.

That is the condition of the license exchange. In Canada, as a visitor, you're required to use the license from the country where you live (Norway, in this case), see the example of Ontario. Driving is not a right, it's a privilege.

Yes, I initially created this question on travel.SE, where it was suggested to ask it here, which I did, but then the question on travel.SE was also moved here. So we essentially have a duplicate.
